# How to run multiple, distinct Fortran scripts in parallel on RHEL 6.9

Tags: shell, parallel-processing, openmp, rhel, gnu-parallel

Let's say I have *N* Fortran executables and *M* cores on my machine, where *N* is greater than *M*. I want to be able to run these executables in parallel. I am using RHEL 6.9

I have used both [OpenMP](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/openMP/) and [GNU Parallel](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/) in the past to run code in parallel. However for my current purposes, neither of these two options would work: RHEL doesn't have a GNU Parallel distribution, and OpenMP applies to parallelizing blocks within a single executable, not multiple executables.

**What is the best way** to run these *N* executables in parallel? Would a simple approach like

```
executable_1 & executable_2 & ... & executable_N
```

work?

Comment: This does not have much to do with Fortran, are you sure you need the fortran tag? I would say you rather need to tag your shell (bash?) or similar.

Comment: Good point. Edited.

Comment: It takes around 3-5 seconds to install **GNU Parallel** http://oletange.blogspot.co.uk/2013/04/why-not-install-gnu-parallel.html

Answer (score 3):

Just because it is not part of the official repository, doesn't mean you cannot use GNU parallel on a RHEL system. Just build [GNU parallel](https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/parallel/parallel-latest.tar.bz2) yourself or [install a third party rpm](https://fr2.rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=parallel).

Answer (score 0):

`xargs` supports parallel execution as well.  Its interface is not ideal for your use case, but this should work:

```
echo executable_1 executable_2 ... executable_N | xargs -n1 -P8 bash -c
```

(`-P8` means “run eight processes in parallel”.)

For more complex tasks, I sometimes write makefiles and use `make -j8` to run targets in parallel.

Comment: `but this should work`. Just be very careful: If you use the output, it is no longer true: https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/parallel_alternatives.html#TESTING-OTHER-TOOLS